# facebook api test submit for review

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework, facebook-permissions

I have an app that is using publish_actions in order to post images from within the game to our app's facebook page.

I am using the iOS social framework (SLRequest and SLServiceTypeFacebook) to get permissions and to actually post the image.

All this works and is verified when I use a test facebook account.

However, I am trying to submit this for review to facebook so I can enable it for the rest of my users. but I am unable to submit because it thinks I am not making the actual API call.

> It looks like you haven't made any API requests to publish content
>   with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days. You need to
>   test this permission in your app with any account listed in Roles
>   before you can submit for review. It looks like you haven't tested
>   this permission because no API request has been made against
>   publish_actions in the last 30 days.

http://cl.ly/image/3g3Q1p13113F

I have tested and confirmed that I can successfully use the publish_actions API to post from the app to the app's facebook page. How can I get facebook to allow me to actually submit this permission for review?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a direct API call to any of the APIs that need `publish_actions` permission? There are some instances where you do not need this permission, namely, if you are using a share dialog. An example of an API that needs `publish_actions` permission is a POST request to `/{user-id}/feed`. Also if you are making a post as a page, you might need `publish_pages` permission instead. e.g. Making a call to `{page-id}/feed` Depending on your use case, try and make a POST request to any endpoint that makes use of these permissions. That should help get rid of the error.

Comment: I am using the internal ios permission dialog and my own in-game share dialog. I am posting a public message and photo to the following url.

Comment: 'NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/34xxxxx509/photos"];'